# Shadow on svg element appears only after double click (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, svg

I have problem with animated SVG on my page (only on Firefox). The box shadow on each element of svg appears only after I double click somewhere on it. Please check this out on [this page](http://cherrydots.pl/).

The shadow is visible right away on any other browser including mobile browsers, only on desktop Firefox the problem exist. I have no idea what double click changes in svg appearance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include a [mcve] in your question. If you fix your page, then this question will be useless to other people in the future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the link to the content is invalid